# Panel data with extremely rare events

Tags: r, panel-data, stata, rare-events

I have panel data consisting of a dependent variable (count) that is greater than zero in only 0.01% of observations. The number of panel units is roughly 3800 and I have 5475 consecutive days of observations for each unit. If I aggregate to monthly, the dependent variable is greater than zero in roughly 2% of all observations. My independent variables are not odd and consist of normal things like temperature, precipitation, etc.

I have been riding a roller-coaster trying to find a suitable method. I am considering survival analysis, fixed effects Poisson (in Stata, xtpoisson), fixed effects logistic in Stata, the rare events logistic function in zelig in R. I have also been intrigued by the idea of using machine learning methods.

Any advice appreciated.

EDIT

I should add that I am interested in both explanatory and predictive approaches, separately if necessary.